# martingale and sub martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Prove that, if $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is  martingale terms of filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that $\max\{X_n,a\},a\in\mathbb{R}$ is a submartingale.

I've done so far

$$\mathbb{E}(\max\{X_{n+1},a\}|\mathcal{F}_n)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbb{E}(a|\mathcal{F}_n),&a\geq X_{n+1}\\
\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n),&a<X_{n+1}
\end{array}\right.=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
a,&a\geq X_{n+1}\\
X_n,&a<X_{n+1}
\end{array}\right.$$

And I don't know what to do next. How should I show that it is greater or equal than $\max\{X_n,a\}$? Please help

Comment: The first equality is not valid.  You can't do this kind of "piecewise" decomposition inside an integral.

Comment: Use Jensen's inequality...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: conditional expectation is monotone.

Clearly $\max\{X_{n+1},a\} \ge a$.  So $E[\max\{X_{n+1},a\} \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \ge \dots ?$

Likewise, $\max\{X_{n+1},a\} \ge X_{n+1}$. So $E[\max\{X_{n+1},a\} \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \ge \dots?$

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much :)